# How do you make Vim key mappings similar to ZZ?

Tags: vim

In Vim you can save all your files and quit by typing `ZZ`.  How can I create a similar mapping but for a different key?  Some keys like `h`, `j`, `k`, and `l` it seems like this would not be possible.  Are there any keys that you could do a similar mapping to `ZZ`?

Comment: You can map any keys you'd like. See `:help map`. E.g., `nmap ohnoes :qall!<NL>` works fine.

Comment: @derobert: still, you have any amount of time to type ZZ. With a mapping you get a timeout.

Comment: @Benoit: That's controlled by `set timeout` and `set ttimeout` and the length by `set timeoutlen`.

Comment: @Benoit You may always map first key to a function that calls `getchar()` and, if got unexpected character, feed it back.

Comment: If you are looking for a "free" (ie not used) keys for your mappings, consider using <leader> key (`:help <Leader>`, default is backslash). It's specially intended for user mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derobert is correct.  There is nothing special about the ZZ type of key combination.

For example, you can create a key shortcut to save all your files without quitting when you type "__" (two underscores) by putting the following in your .vimrc:

```
nmap __ :wa<CR>
```